# OpenLDAP as a Proxy cache only, no local database

Tags: proxy, cache, openldap

I am trying to get a local LDAP proxy cache running. The idea is this:

- Currently a computer `(A)` is sending all ldap requests to a remote ldap server `(L)`
- Instead of that, there should be a proxy cache "server" running on `A` to act as an intermediate between `A` and `L`. The cache would store all queries and all their attributes (until it is filled up and then it starts "recycling").

[OpenLDAP's Proxy Cache Engine](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html) looks pretty good, but there is not much information about how to set it up. There is an example config file, but I cannot get it to work.

As this is supposed to only be a proxy cache, I shouldn't need to set up a local database. So the config file looks like this:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

moduleload pcache.la

database        ldap
suffix          "dc=int,dc=somedomain,dc=com"
rootdn          "dc=int,dc=somedomain,dc=com"
uri             ldap://dc-04.int.somedomain.com:389

overlay pcache
pcache         hdb 100000 1 1000 100
pcacheAttrset  0 *
pcacheTemplate (sn=) 0 3600

cachesize 20
directory /var/lib/ldap
index       objectClass eq
index       cn eq,sub
```

Now I would expect that any request to ldap://localhost would mirror to the remote LDAP, if not in the cache.

I use this command to test the auth on the remote server:

```
ldapwhoami -vvv -h dc-04.int.somedomain.com -p 389 -D melka@somedomain.com -x -w <passwd>
```

Which works well, I get the auth.

However, when I try to run the same command on localhost:

```
ldapwhoami -vvv -h localhost -p 389 -D melka@somedomain.com -x -w <passwd>
```

It fails, saying

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://localhost:389 )
ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
    additional info: invalid DN
```

Slapd is listening on localhost, netstat contains this line:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      10352/slapd
```

Is there something I am missing? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
>       additional info: invalid DN

This means that an invalid distinguished name was used. Note that using something like `melka@somedomain.com` as bind DN in a simple bind request only works for MS Active Directory and no other LDAP server. Therefore your local LDAP proxy denies this request without doing something else.